# Why is the team called / named U.N.C.L.E?

Tags: the-man-from-u.n.c.l.e

I'm talking about [The Man from U.N.C.L.E](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1638355/)

At the middle of the movie, I thought uncle Rudi will play a vital role and the film was named after him. But at the end scenes we saw basically the team of three (Solo, Illya & Gaby) is given a name "U.N.C.L.E". But why? What's the meaning of that name?

They're basically from three intelligence (CIA, Russian, British). It doesn't reflect that too. What does U.N.C.L.E represent? Did I miss it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you actually read that link, you'd see it was explained in the movie's MB.  ;o)

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1638355/board/nest/248914054?ref_=tt_bd_6

**United Network Command For Law Enforcement**

Comment: What is an "MB"?

Comment: @Napoleon Wilson  Apparently, Message Boards. I'm just glad it wasn't short for IMDB!

Comment: Being that I linked directly **to** the messageboard, I thought it was self-explanatory.  ;o)